# Trying to build a function to count unique pixels in image

Tags: c, colors, pixel, bmp

..which is something useful. However.. i couldn't see anything related on the i-net ..which appears to be a bit problematic. Thats why.. i tried to build the function by myself:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned long dword;

typedef struct
{
    byte R;
    byte G;
    byte B;
} RGB;

dword
getpixels
(char *FILE_NAME)
{
    dword WIDTH = 500; // example dimension
    dword HEIGHT = 500; // example dimension
    FILE* fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb");
    #define HEADERS_SIZE 54

    byte color[3];
    byte colorTable[50000][3]; // maximum 50000 pixels
    int val = (-1), valr;

    dword l;
    dword count = 0;

    fseek(fp, HEADERS_SIZE, SEEK_SET); // move iterator to where the pixels start fromS

    // alternate : fread(&valr, 1, 1, fp) == 1
    while( (valr = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) // runs the code while this is true
    {
        val++; // increment index
        if(val > 2) val = 0;
        color[val] = valr;

        for(l=0; l<50000; l++) {
        if(val == 2 && color[0] != colorTable[l][0] && color[1] != colorTable[l][1] && color[2] != colorTable[l][2])
        {
            colorTable[l][0] = color[0];
            colorTable[l][1] = color[1];
            colorTable[l][2] = color[2];
            count++;
        }
        }

        fseek(fp, WIDTH%4, SEEK_CUR); // skip padding
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return count;
}
```

As you already probably felt.. the function isn't working because.. i don't know. Thats what i'm actually asking. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following (not tested, use at your own peril). I've renamed a few variables to make the code a little more self-explanatory.

**Edit:** Updated to actually include the color counter which I missed in the first version (assuming that is what you wanted from your question). Keep in mind that this is slow since you are just doing a slow linear lookup in the color table. For a 500x500 image with 50000 colors you could be doing 10 billion loops.

```
int numColors = 0;
int colorIndex = 0;
int inputColor;
int colorCounts[50000];  //Be aware of possible overflow

memset(colorCounts, 0, sizeof(int)*50000);  // Initialize counters

while( (inputColor = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) 
{
    color[colorIndex] = inputColor;
    colorIndex++;

    fseek(fp, WIDTH%4, SEEK_CUR);

    if (colorIndex < 3) continue;  // or use an if block
    colorIndex = 0;

    for (l = 0; l < numColors; ++l) 
    {
        if (color[0] == colorTable[l][0] && 
            color[1] == colorTable[l][1] && 
            color[2] == colorTable[l][2])
        { 
            ++colorCounts[l]; // Update counter
            break;
        }
    }

    if (l >= numColors)
    {
       if (numColors >= 50000) exit(1);  //Or do something else appropriate
       colorTable[numColors][0] = color[0];
       colorTable[numColors][1] = color[1];
       colorTable[numColors][2] = color[2];

       colorCounts[l] = 1;   //Initialize counter

        ++numColors;
    }

}
```

**Edit 2:** Code to print the color table to help you debug things (add to end of function to display colors found):

```
for (l = 0; l < numColors; ++l)
{
    printf("%d) %02X %02X %02X\n", l, colorTable[l][0], colorTable[l][1], colorTable[l][2]);
}
```

Comment: I left my code on processing. I came back after like.. 1 hour and i realized it returned 399000. So umm.. my code works but extremely slow?

Comment: Hmm it returned 4 on full white picture. It doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Updated to include the actual counting code which I missed in the first version...assuming that is what you were looking for.

Comment: It seems my additional counting code is not necessary (remove the `countCounts` array if you don't need it), but I tested the counting function and it seems to work fine. Perhaps the issue is your file input code or your file contents?

Comment: I'm using varieties of different bmp x24 images. I will test the updated code :) And i hope it works.. because that question left me without rights to ask.. so i hope it wasn't for nothing.

Comment: If it is a BMP file then be aware that the padding is at the end of a row and not between pixels. Also make sure the BMP pixel data is not compressed.

Comment: it is not compressed. How to set the padding skip to your code?

Comment: and is there any faster way though? For larger images.. its going to take millenias.

Comment: Both those question are complex enough to be worthy of their own SO question if you need further help.

Comment: But.. it doesn't work. It returns 7 with a picture of white and cyan in it. If i draw more cyan pixels.. it will return more.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your BMP loading code. It works fine for me with a few test in-memory buffers and with run-times less than 15 ms (in debug builds no less).

Comment: Try printing the colours found at the end of the function to you help debug things. I've added a short snippet of code to do that to my answer. This should tell you what colours are found and let you see how they differ from the expected result.

Comment: How that would help me. Note that this is not an console application. I can't use `printf`, `scanf`, `getc`, `gets` etc.

Comment: So change it to something you can use. Step-through it with a debugger, output to the debug window, output to a log file, etc....